# CGAffineTransformRotate in viewDidLoad stretches/distords the UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I need to rotate by a given angle a UIImageView created by Interface builder when the view is loaded.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
    image.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(image.transform, REF_INIT_OFFSET*M_PI/180); 
}
```

This rotates the image but the latter is totally distorted and stretched. If REF_INIT_OFFSET is a multiple of 90 it works fine !

Here is how the picture should look like (note the needle pointing to the "0")

[image]

and here is how it actually looks:

[image]

it looks like the image is stretched into a wrong direction.

Do you have in idea what's wrong ?

thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure that it help you, but I had the same problem after [UIImage setFrame:] if UIImage was transformed , the decision was using setBounds instead of setFrame

**Solving the problem on the discussion in the comments:**

Method setFrame is called after viewDidLoad in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation implicitly if autoresizesSubviews property YES

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.view.autoresizesSubviews=NO;
image.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(image.transform, 50*M_PI/180);
}
```

Comment: Just test your situation, it seems that the method setFrame is called after viewDidLoad in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation implicitly if autoresizesSubviews property YES. But I can't get this error again after first change autoresizesSubviews value

Comment: Actually I have the same problem after I rotate the UI when the device orientation is changed ..  What exactly shall I "test" ?

Comment: This help to me:- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.autoresizesSubviews=NO;
    image.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(image.transform, 50*M_PI/180);  But is your image subview of self.view or of one its subview?

}

Comment: `self.view.autoresizesSubviews = NO;` that seems to be the solution ! thanks !

Comment: sorry, I'm a newbie in Stack Overflow .. how can I accept your last comment as the solution ?

Comment: I'm newbie too and don't know right way, so I edit my first answer - it looks clearer than comments